# Editorconfig for python docstring

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation, docstring, editorconfig

I am using the `pycharm` IDE and I would like to automatize the indentation of the python `docstrings` with the `.editorconfig` file. I get to control almost everything with the following configuration (just in case it is useful):

```
[{*.py,*.pyw}]
ij_python_align_collections_and_comprehensions = true
ij_python_align_multiline_imports = true
ij_python_align_multiline_parameters = true
ij_python_align_multiline_parameters_in_calls = true
ij_python_blank_line_at_file_end = true
ij_python_blank_lines_after_imports = 1
ij_python_blank_lines_after_local_imports = 0
ij_python_blank_lines_around_class = 1
ij_python_blank_lines_around_method = 1
ij_python_blank_lines_around_top_level_classes_functions = 2
ij_python_blank_lines_before_first_method = 0
ij_python_call_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_python_call_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_python_call_parameters_wrap = normal
ij_python_dict_alignment = 0
ij_python_dict_new_line_after_left_brace = false
ij_python_dict_new_line_before_right_brace = false
ij_python_dict_wrapping = 1
ij_python_from_import_new_line_after_left_parenthesis = false
ij_python_from_import_new_line_before_right_parenthesis = false
ij_python_from_import_parentheses_force_if_multiline = false
ij_python_from_import_trailing_comma_if_multiline = false
ij_python_from_import_wrapping = 1
ij_python_hang_closing_brackets = false
ij_python_keep_blank_lines_in_code = 1
ij_python_keep_blank_lines_in_declarations = 1
ij_python_keep_indents_on_empty_lines = false
ij_python_keep_line_breaks = true
ij_python_method_parameters_new_line_after_left_paren = false
ij_python_method_parameters_right_paren_on_new_line = false
ij_python_method_parameters_wrap = normal
ij_python_new_line_after_colon = false
ij_python_new_line_after_colon_multi_clause = true
ij_python_optimize_imports_always_split_from_imports = false
ij_python_optimize_imports_case_insensitive_order = false
ij_python_optimize_imports_join_from_imports_with_same_source = false
ij_python_optimize_imports_sort_by_type_first = true
ij_python_optimize_imports_sort_imports = true
ij_python_optimize_imports_sort_names_in_from_imports = false
ij_python_space_after_comma = true
ij_python_space_after_number_sign = true
ij_python_space_after_py_colon = true
ij_python_space_before_backslash = true
ij_python_space_before_comma = false
ij_python_space_before_for_semicolon = false
ij_python_space_before_lbracket = false
ij_python_space_before_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_python_space_before_method_parentheses = false
ij_python_space_before_number_sign = true
ij_python_space_before_py_colon = false
ij_python_space_within_empty_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_python_space_within_empty_method_parentheses = false
ij_python_spaces_around_additive_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_assignment_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_bitwise_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_eq_in_keyword_argument = false
ij_python_spaces_around_eq_in_named_parameter = false
ij_python_spaces_around_equality_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_multiplicative_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_power_operator = true
ij_python_spaces_around_relational_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_around_shift_operators = true
ij_python_spaces_within_braces = false
ij_python_spaces_within_brackets = false
ij_python_spaces_within_method_call_parentheses = false
ij_python_spaces_within_method_parentheses = false
ij_python_use_continuation_indent_for_arguments = false
ij_python_use_continuation_indent_for_collection_and_comprehensions = false
ij_python_use_continuation_indent_for_parameters = true
ij_python_wrap_long_lines = false
```

It would be rather useful to manage all the indentation config from the same file. That is, adding the docstring configuration to the .editorconfig. Someone knows if it is possible to control the `docstring` style by using .editorconfig?

Comment: curious, I'm not able to get it to auto-format when working on a py file. did you have to add additional changes to get the editorconfig settings to apply?

Comment: @rv.kvetch you need to install the plugin EditorConfig. Then go to Settings>Editor>Code Style>General (tab).

Then you should hit on the `Enable EditorConfig support` check box. Click on Apply.

ATTOW the default shorthand for formatting the file is Alt+Shitf+L but it may vary depending on your locale. You can also go to Code>reformat Code

Comment: Ah got it, thanks. I had editorconfig plugin installed already - to reformat code on mac I used shortcut `option+cmd+L`. I might have actually mistaken how editorconfig is used. I thought it would auto-format every time I save the file, like it does when I work in Rust and CLion. Side story, but it would be pretty cool if there was a way to get it to auto-format (using editorconfig) on file save.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yeah you can trigger several things when saving. Just go to Settings>Tools>Actions on Save, then hit the "Reformat code" checkbox and apply the changes

Comment: man, you're a lifesaver. thanks. I can't believe I've been using PyCharm for so long and somehow missed that toggle option in settings.